# TableView rows get mixed up when scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a tableview in a UIViewController and I have subclass of UITableViewCell.
I register the cell in viewDidLoad;
- In cellForRowAtIndexPath, I use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier to get the cell and I reset all the labels to the right values; However, when the table scrolls, the top rows and the bottom rows get mixed up and the labels get interchanged. I don't know why this would happen when I am resetting the cells to the right values for each row. Do you have any idea why the mix up happens.

```
[self.myFoldersTableView registerClass:[QConnectFoldersTVCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:QMY_FOLDERS_CELL_ID];
```

and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    QConnectFoldersTVCell *cell = (QConnectFoldersTVCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSMutableDictionary *cellDataDict = [self findCellDataAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.mainLabel.text = cellDataDict[FOLDER_CELL_DICT_KEY_MAIN_TEXT];
    cell.detailLabel.text = cellDataDict[FOLDER_CELL_DICT_KEY_DETAIL_TEXT];
    cell.folderCellType = [cellDataDict[FOLDER_CELL_DICT_KEY_TYPE] intValue];         


    return cell;
}
```

- I want to add that I have printed out the label values being set for the row and the data is right for each row. The cells are being reset to the correct data in the above function. So I don't know why something else is displayed on screen.

Comment: Could you share your code for the `findCellDataAtIndexPath:` method? It doesn't look like there's anything wrong with the code you have posted so far.

Comment: Actually, findCellDataAtIndexPath is working fine. It is a complicated code, since I have sections within sections, so I don't want to make the question confusing by posting it. I am certain that it's working fine because I have printed out the the data being returned by this function and the data is always correct.

Comment: In your cell class : `QConnectFoldersTVCell`, make sure you implement `-(void)prepareForReuse` method, and reset your subviews content

Comment: Although, I can add that I am using two tableviews in one uiviewcontroller. I am switching between the two tableviews using UIViews transitionFromView:toview function. Switching between them seems to work fine.

Comment: Vinzzz, I tried using prepareForReuse in my cell subclass to reset the values to some defaults. However, the defaults show up in cellForRowAtIndexPath when cells are dequeued and they seem to be reset to the correct row data values. but then the mix up shows up on screen.

Comment: There's no need to use prepareForReuse in your situation. If you want any help, you're going to have to post the findCellDataAtIndexPath method. There's nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: I am suspicious about your `findCellDataAtIndexPath` too - why does it return an `NSMutableDictionary` ? - From a design point of view it should return non-mutable objects unless there is a need to return mutable objects, but the reason this makes me suspicious is it makes me think you may be mutating a single dictionary inside your method

Comment: what if cell is nil after dequeuing?

Comment: I have posted the solution to my problem below. It had to do with my use of layoutSubviews. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I found the reason for the mixup. In my tableViewCell subclass, I was using layoutSubviews to do initialization for the labels because the actual size of the cell isn't available in init but is available in layoutSubviews. Removing layoutSubviews override seems to have stopped the row mixup of data/values.

  ```
  - (void)layoutSubviews
  {
      [super layoutSubviews];
      CGSize size = self.contentView.frame.size;
      CGFloat mainHeight = ((size.height * 6)/10) - 6.0;
      CGFloat detailHeight = ((size.height*4)/10) - 6.0;
      self.mainLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8.0, 4.0, size.width - 16.0, mainHeight)];
      self.detailLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8.0, 4.0+(self.mainLabel.frame.size.height)+4.0, size.width - 16.0, detailHeight)];    
  }
  ```